# rails-i18n not working for header error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n

I'm using the [rails-i18n gem](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n) to use `:hr` for my main language.

The gem works but for `header message` it doesn't.

(The `4 errors prohibited this list from being saved:` part)

This is what I get when I submit the form with invalid atributes:

```
4 errors prohibited this list from being saved:             #doesn't translate
    Field1 ne smije biti prazan                              #translates/presence
    Field2 ne smije biti prazan                              #translates/presence
    Field3 ne smije biti prazan                              #translates/presence
    Filed4 nije odgovarajuće duljine (treba biti 11 znakova) #translates/length
```

As for the code, I only added `config.i18n.default_locale = :hr` to `config/application.rb`.

In the documentation in says:

> Following locales are complete:
>
> bs, da, en, en-US, es-PA, **hr**, is, ja, nl, sr, ur, zh-HK

Tested with other locales but is still doesn't translate the `4 errors prohibited this list from being saved:` part.

Am I doing something wrong or there are translations missing in the `.yml` files ?

Note: I use rails 4.0.0

**Update:**

```
<%= form_for(@report) do |f| %>
  <% if @report.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@report.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this list from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @report.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-container">

    <div class="inline half">
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :field1 %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :field1 %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :field2 %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :field2 %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :field3 %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :field3 %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :field4 %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :field4 %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inline half">

      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Create", class: "continue-button" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Is your locale file is up to date ? Try to download the latest yml file and put it in your config/locales folder: https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale

Comment: @Baldrick tried that already, I put manually the `.yml` in the `locales` folder but the result is the same.

Comment: can you post your form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As some fields clearly translate, I think you have to look for the "errors prohibited..." message. This message should be in your activerecord.hr.yml file, and should look like

```
hr:
  errors:
    messages:
      not_saved:
        one: '1 error prohibited this %{resource} from being saved:'
        other: '%{count} errors prohibited this %{resource} from being saved:'
```

(but then in your language)

Now change in your view the code

```
= pluralize(@report.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this list from being saved:
```

into

```
t('errors.messages.not_saved', count: @report.errors.count, resource: Report.model_name.human)
```

In order to get the "Report", mentioned in Report.model_name.human translated into Hungarian, you should add something to your hr.yml file like

```
activerecord:
  models:
    report: Translation of report in Hungarian
    reports: Translation of reports in Hungarian
```

That should give you complete flexibility...

Comment: Very strange indeed. Don't know what the cause could be, as this is exactly how I have it in my applications, and they work fine...

Comment: I also deleted this gem and put manually only your code in the .yml file but that also doesn't translate that message.

Comment: @Vucko - can you try to change it as modified in my answer? I added the "errors" layer

Comment: Did you explicitely add it to the .yml file, as I just found out that the not_saved error is NOT in the yml.hr file on github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale

Comment: Yes, I added that part to the hr.yml file. I also removed all other translations in the `messages` and only put your code but it still doesn't translate.

Comment: Yes, I'm also using the devise-i18n gem for devise translatons and it's working just fine. Even the header (`not_saved`) message is being translated.

Comment: @Vucko, I finally understand: you explicitely put in your view: ><%= pluralize(@report.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this list from being saved
That is the reason this is not translated of course. You should use one of the i18n helpers here, doing something like t('errors.messages.not_saved', count: nr, resource: object)

Comment: Yes, this works but what about the `errors.template.header` part in the `hr.yml` file ? It has the matching translations so I believe that those translations are ment to be in the _header message error_.

Comment: It is mentioned in https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/issues/118 that this is no longer used... (remark of Kuroda in the middle of the page)

Comment: How did I not see that, especially after spending hour of searching for the solution. Thank you for the answer and comments :)
Note: it's Croatian, not Hungarian :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try changing `<%= pluralize(@report.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this list from being saved:` for `<%= t( :errors, :count => @report.errors.count, :model => t("model.Report")) %>` it will take the model and errors from the following places

```
hr:
  model:
    Report: "Report"
  errors:
    one: "%{model} can't be saved... 1 error custom message."
    other: "%{model} can't be saved for %{count} custom errors"
```

Comment: This seems to work. But why then doesn't the gems .yml file work?

Comment: Let me formulate the question, what has to be change in the `hr.yml` to make it work with `pluralize` ( `<h2><%= pluralize(@report.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this list from being saved:</h2>`)?